# SQL SELECT statement with WHERE statement in with DropDownList ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql-server-2008, select, where-clause

Please take a look at the this code:

```
Dim query As String = "SELECT * From Table Where ID = @UserID"
Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(query)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", DropDownList1.SelectedValue)
```

and this HTML markup

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" Width="300px">
     <asp:ListItem Text=">>>>>>>>>>> ALL USERS <<<<<<<<<<<" Value="-1" />
     <asp:ListItem Text="Tom" Value="1" />
     <asp:ListItem Text="Jack" Value="2" />
</asp:DropDownList>
```

I know y'all understand that when the user select user "tom" will get all data UserID = 1 and if the user select user "Jack" will get all data UserID = 2 right! OK what I need is how to get all the data from table if the user Select "ALL USERS" ?? What can I do in this case? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim query As String
IF User = -1 Then
   query = "SELECT * From Table "
ELSEIF
   query = "SELECT * From Table Where ID = @UserID"
End If

Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(query)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", DropDownList1.SelectedValue)
```

Comment: you may also try using **SELECT * From Table Where ID = ID** that give all data from table.

Comment: THANKS ^_^ THAT'S WHAT I BEEN LOOKING FOR

Comment: please vote for the answer and marked it as answer :)